# bootstrap3 progress bar not running when i run code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

hi guys the progress bar doesnt display when i run the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used your code at  http://jsbin.com/ejUxAjAv/1/ and it shows for me using a Chrome browser (version 31.0.1650.63).

It doesn't work for some browsers.

From http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

> Cross-browser compatibility
>   Progress bars use CSS3 transitions and
>   animations to achieve some of their effects. These features are not
>   supported in Internet Explorer 9 and below or older versions of
>   Firefox. Opera 12 does not support animations.

Comment: am running Version 32.0.1700.72 , which seems to be higher than yours

Comment: The small difference in chrome versions won't affect the CSS3. What happens when you got to http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css ?

Comment: I was also able to see the progress bar using Firefox (version 26.0). Does Firefox work for you?

Comment: no worries , i downlaod bootrap and put in my files, it works now, thanks for help, i appreciate